# Where can I download the jar file for DB2 version 8.2?

Tags: database, oracle, db2

Where can I download the jar file for DB2 version 8.2 ?
I could find the latest version but not the 8.2 version on IBM's page
Trying to migrate DB2 8.2 to Oracle 11g Any help appreciated.

Comment: What does "the JAR file" mean in this context?  There are probably millions of JAR files that you might be referring to.  Are you looking for a JDBC driver, for example?  Why is this tagged Oracle as well?

Comment: I am trying to migrate DB2 8.2 to Oracle 11g, so as per the Oracle steps http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/connect-step-db2-1946321.html You need to browse the jar file drivers into SQL developer as a 3rd party database. What are the other ways to migrate the same ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Various DB2 client packages can be found here:  [Download Fix Packs by version for IBM Data Server Client Packages](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27016878) DB2 8 is long out of support, but you should be fine using version 9.1 or 9.5 of the driver. What you need is probably just the JDBC driver.